# How to synchronize file writing to achieve maximum concurrency between threads Java

Tags: java, file, synchronization, locking

I have 10 text files, that I use to store records. In my application, I have couple of operations, e.g write to file and edit file (if the specified line is found I create a temp file and transfer all info there, then delete the old and rename the temp file).

All my clients will have access to the 10 text files, so I want synchronize their activities to maintain data consistency.

I want to lock or synchronize a file if a client is editing or writing, say f1.txt so no other can write/edit to it and increase concurrency by letting another client to edit f2.txt in the same time.

```
public void writeToFile(String pathname){
File f1 = new File(pathname)
synchronize (f1) {.. // do something}
}
```

My problem here is that am creating a new file everytime with a specific path.

Please I would appreciate any guidance and help, am you to this.

Thanks

Comment: Have a boolean writeFlag, and set it to true, whenever anyone tries to read/write from/to a file. You need to check this boolean first as a precondition if it is set to true before reading/writing from a file.

Comment: Your solution has a race condition.  You need to synchronize on _something_.  Also I think the OP wants to lock on specific files, so that if Thread A is writing File A, then Thread B can go ahead and write File B.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to synchronize on a particular file path (and the file system is not enforcing this in a way you like).  You are correct the the `File` object will not work.  What you need to synchronize on is the *name* of the file.

```
public void writeToFile(String pathname){
File f1 = new File(pathname)
synchronize (f1.getCanonicalPath().intern()) {.. // do something}
}
```

The `getCanonicalPath` method will return the same `String` value for any two `File` objects that reference the same path.  For example, if `../logs/mylog.txt` and `/var/spool/logs/mylog.txt` are the same file, they will have the same canonical path.

The `intern` method returns the same *reference* for any two `String` object with the same `value`.  So, what you end up locking on is a singleton instance of the canonical path for the file.

I think that meets your needs.

Comment: Actually I want to synchronize on the file itself. Meaning, if a thread is writing to file1.txt then no other threads can access file1.txt but they will be able to access other files if only these files are not locked. I just want to maintain the data consistency in the system because all threads can access all files I have, so I should synchronize the operations. Does your approach helps to achieve this synchronization? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this approach will do what you want. As you noted, you can't synchronized on the `File` object, because you can have many `File` objects for the same file.  The trick is to find a singleton that is unique for each unique file.  There are, perhaps, other ways to do this, but the approach I've shown creates such a singleton.  It's a `String` that uniquely corresponds to a specific file.